# How to limit the write speed of core dump in linux , which would make the load dramatically high.

Tags: linux, coredump

we meet a problem when process crashed and then core dump . Due to the big memory occupation of the process- about 20GB, the core dump need to write 20GB core data to the disk, then the disk usage become very high and the load increase dramatically.

How to limit the write speed of core dump ? A process crash make the server hang, it is too bad.

Comment: Do you even want a core dump? If not, disable them (see  Basile Starynkevitch's answer).

Answer (score 5):

I believe there is no simple way.

However, on Linux, you could use the `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file (see [core(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) and [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) man pages), and you could even -when that `core_pattern` starts with a pipe symbol `|`- write core to a program (or script), which then could slow down the writing.

Alternatively you could have some user-space file system (e.g. thru [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)).

And the `core` file might be a symlink to something elsewhere (e.g. a FUSE filesystem which would slow down the writing, or simply a fast filesystem on some SSD disk).

Of course, you could also avoid dumping core (by [setrlimit(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) or the shell's `ulimit` builtin, or by starting the program thru `gdb --args` ....)

And I imagine that if you [ionice(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) appropriately the command, all the disk I/O could be reasonably slowed down.

<sup>PS. I never tested any of these ideas, so I might be wrong.</sup>